# Как разархивировать архив с паролем? (с#)

Tags: c#, zip

Нашел в документации вот такой код:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFile, targetFolder);
```

он разархивирует zip архив в папку, он работает, но что если на архиве пароль? как разархвровать архив в таком случае?

Comment: `как разархвровать архив в таком случае?` - использовать любую другую, стороннюю библиотеку.

Comment: Неужели стандартные библиотеки не предоставляют возможность разархивировать архив с паролем? И если так, то какие сторонние библиотеки подойдут для этой цели?

Comment: Ну, на сколько я знаю, не умеет. Она больше созданы для сжатия трафика и другие подобные механизмы, где нужна быстрота и минимализм) Скажем так, это не полноценный архиватор, вот и все. `какие сторонние библиотеки подойдут для этой цели?`  - любые, вот прям напишите в GitHub запрос "Zip" и вам выдаст кучу вариантов, берите любую. Допустим [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/).